# Not able to access variables of @ConfigurationProperties class using reflection?

Tags: java, spring-boot, reflection

Below are the entries which are there in YML files in spring boot project.

```
application:
  applicationPath: "/demo"
  defaultFilePath: ${application.applicationPath}childDemo/import_files/
  actDocsPath: ${application.applicationPath}childDemo2/act_docs/
  bgJobsLogs: ${application.applicationPath}childDemo3/bgjobs_logs/
```

On these location I keep some document in my project.

Requirement is..  on project startup I want to create all these directory structure, so for that I created one class...

```
package com.sbill.app.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
public class ApplicationProperties {

    @Value("${application.applicationPath}")
    public String applicationPath;

    @Value("${application.defaultFilePath}")
    public String defaultFilePath;

    @Value("${application.actDocsPath}")
    public String actDocsPath;

    @Value("${application.bgJobsLogs}")
    public String bgJobsLogs;

    public String getDefaultFilePath() {
        return defaultFilePath;
    }

    public void setDefaultFilePath(String defaultFilePath) {
        this.defaultFilePath = defaultFilePath;
    }

    public String getActDocsPath() {
        return actDocsPath;
    }

    public void setActDocsPath(String actDocsPath) {
        this.actDocsPath = actDocsPath;
    }

    public String getBgJobsLogs() {
        return bgJobsLogs;
    }

    public String getApplicationPath() {
        return applicationPath;
    }

    public void setApplicationPath(String applicationPath) {
        this.applicationPath = applicationPath;
    }
}
```

And one class i created where i have implemented with `CommandLineRunner` to invoke on startup

```
package com.sbill.app.config;

import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.sbill.app.domain.User;
import com.sbill.app.repository.UserRepository;
import com.sbill.app.service.util.FieldReqValidationUtil;

@Component
public class SbillStartupRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println(applicationProperties.getDefaultFilePath());  
        System.out.println(applicationProperties.getApplicationPath()); 

        Field[] fields = applicationProperties.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for(Field f : fields){
            f.setAccessible(true);
           Class t = f.getType();
           Object v = f.get(applicationProperties);

           File applicationpath = new File(v.toString());
            if (!applicationpath.exists()) {
                if (applicationpath.mkdirs()) {
                    System.out.println("Directory is created!");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Failed to create directory!");
                }
            }
           System.out.println(applicationpath.getAbsolutePath());


        }
    }
}
```

**Here my problem is :-**  With setter/getter path is getting print , but using reflection i am not able to access fields..

Comment: Why do you have `@Value`?

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike-   yes value anotation should not be there... actually this class already was created just my task is to  create directory but i don't think that issue is related to value annotation...  using setter/getter i am able to access values

Comment: A property (using getter/setter) isn't a `Field`. As the `Field `is `private` you cannot acces it. Next to that you are probably getting a proxy class instead of the actual class. But why use reflection? Just use the getters instead of trying this with reflection? What is the gain?

Comment: @M.Deinum  I need to iterate over all the fields of the ApplicationProperties.java that's why using reflection , without reflection using getters how can i do this ?

Comment: Why? There are getters for all the fields... So again why would you need reflection, without getters/setters the `@ConfigurationProperties` won't work. Looks like you are trying to make a generic solution with a complex thing like reflection. If you really want to use reflection (I would advice against it) is to use the Spring `ReflectionUtils.doWithFields` methods and implement the `FieldFilter` and `FieldCallback` using a lambda expression.

Comment: `getClass()` will return the actual class of the object, e.g. it might be a subclass, and `getDeclaredFields()` only returns fields declared in that very class. To get the fields declared in `ApplicationProperties`, just use `ApplicationProperties.class.getDeclaredFields()`.

Comment: @Holger  Thanks for your valuable solution.  This is what i was looking for. it works properly now.... thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getClass()` will return the actual class of the object, e.g. it might be a subclass, and `getDeclaredFields()` only returns fields declared in that very class. To get the fields declared in `ApplicationProperties`, just use `ApplicationProperties.class.getDeclaredFields()`.

Note that you can improve the code by using [`AccessibleObject.setAccessible`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible-java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject:A-boolean-), to set the accessibility status of all objects at once, to avoid repeated potentially expensive security checks. Also, the use of [NIO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createDirectories-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-) is strongly recommended here, as it allows to make a diagnosis when the creation of the directories failed, rather than returning an unhelpful `boolean` value.

```
Field[] fields = ApplicationProperties.class.getDeclaredFields();
AccessibleObject.setAccessible(fields, true);
for(Field f : fields){
    Object v = f.get(applicationProperties);
    Path p = Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(v.toString()));
    System.out.println(p.toAbsolutePath());
}
```